# How to set Request as Authenticated with Custom Identity details?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

My project requires a custom authentication, with user name, password and a custom, third element.

I have written the custom code to verify the entered details and determine if they are authenticated or not, but when I draw the screens, the Request seems to not be flagged as authenticated.

_LoginPartial.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@* this always evaluates to false - Why? *@
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @* stuff happens here *@
    }
}
else
{
        @* other stuff happens here *@
}
```

My controller that handles login requests follows the expected flow when I step through it in debug. The relevant method is:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    CustomAuthenticator authenticator = new CustomAuthenticator(repository);
    SignInStatus result = authenticator.Authenticate(model.CustomElement, model.UserName, model.Password);
    if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
    {
        CustomIdentity ident = (CustomIdentity)authenticator.Principal.Identity;
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true }, ident);
        if (returnUrl == null)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The Authenticate() method does what needs to be done to check the (non-Identity) tables to validate the provided credentials. It then creates the custom Identity and Principal. The Login() code above passes this identity to the OwinContext AuthenticationManager.

Here are parts of the custom Principal:

```
public class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    public IIdentity Identity { get; set; }

    public CustomPrincipal(CustomIdentity identity)
    {
        Identity = identity;
    }
}
```

and Identity:

```
public class CustomIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
    public CustomIdentity(string authenticationType) : base(authenticationType) { }

    public string CustomDetail { get; set; }
}
```

And in Startup.cs I have the following in the Configuration() method:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login/Login"),
});
```

I have worked through Identity tutorials like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn745860.aspx) and a couple others without success.

What am I missing? Why is my successful authentication process not marking the Request as Authenticated?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287634/owin-authentication-signin-not-working)?

Comment: Yes, @CamiloTerevinto. A similar issue, but theirs cleared up when they called the extracted method. In my case the app.UseCookieAuthentication() call is happening, but still no successful sign-in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my issue was in the string authentication-type being passed in to my CustomIdentity and on to the ClaimsIdentity base class. With a value of "ApplicationCookie" the Request would be marked as Authenticated in such a way that _LoginPartial.cshtml would find.

```
public class CustomIdentity : ClaimsIdentity
{
    // Must set an authentication type for IsAuthenticated to be true
    public CustomIdentity(string authenticationType) : base(authenticationType) {}
    // ...
}
```

I had read somewhere that any string could be used, and was initially calling the constructor with a value such as "Password" e.g.

```
ClaimsIdentity myIdentity = new CustomIdentity("Password");
```

When I changed the string value for authenticationType to "ApplicationCookie" all behaved as expected.

```
ClaimsIdentity myIdentity = new CustomIdentity("ApplicationCookie");
```

One final note: I also had an @Html.AntiForgeryToken() that required that I explicitly include Name Identifier and Identity Provider claims:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
    new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", "CEP_UAS")
};
```